# When do you gain life from lifelink when attacking?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When do you gain the life from lifelink when attacking?  Is it right when the attacks happen, or is it at the end of your attack phase?

Answer (score 7):

You will gain the life at the same time that the damage is dealt. Lifelink simply changes what the effects of dealing are, to include gaining life.

From the [basic rule book](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf):

> lifelink—If a creature with lifelink deals damage, its controller also gains that much life.

Note that some creatures, such as [Horned Cheetah](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHorned%20Cheetah%5d) have a similar ability to Lifelink, but it works slightly different. As a triggered ability, Horned Cheetah's ability will go on the stack when damage is dealt, and ou will gain life after that ability resolves.

So with Lifelink... you are at 1 life, and your opponent is attacking you with 2 1/1 creatures. You can block one of them with a [Vampire Nighthawk](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVampire%20Nighthawk%5d), but can’t block the other. When combat damage is dealt, you lose 1 life and gain 2 life simultaneously, so you do not lose the game.

If instead you had a Horned Cheetah to block with, then you would lose the game before you gain the life fro Horned Cheetah.

Comment: ya i meant lifelink (to much league of legends)

Comment: Ya that's how i figured it happened, thanks for the answer. :)

Comment: @cory If this answered your question (and a better answer doesn’t come along), please use the check mark to mark this as the answer

Comment: Incidentally, when Lifelink was first keyworded in Tenth Edition it was a triggered ability like Horned Cheetah has.  So they went and errataed all the old cards to have Lifelink.  Then they changed Lifelink during the M10 rules overhaul to act like it does now and de-errattaed all of the older cards that were now functionally different from lifelink... except for Loxodon Warhammer, which had been reprinted in Tenth Edition with Lifelink.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is good, I just like to reference the comprehensive rulebook. Rule 119.3 details the effects of damage being dealt. For instance, 119.3a says

> Damage dealt to a player by a source without infect causes that player to lose that much life.

And 119.3f says

> Damage dealt by a source with lifelink causes that source’s controller to gain that much life, 
>   in addition to the damage’s other results.

So a player losing life from being dealt damage, and a player gaining life from dealing lifelink-damage, are both treated equally by the rules, and happens simultaneously as an integral part of what "deal damage" means.